# JQUERY live with AJAX

Tags: jquery, load, live, image

I want to use AJAX with .live() so i can make things neat. I wan to know how it is done, I have provided a basic function: on a button click a  tag is placed in a . But i need to use live() in order to use a lightbox on that image.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("button").click(function()
    {
        $("div").load('test1.txt')
    });
});
```

**LIGHTBOX:**

```
$(function()
{
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* jQuery lightBox plugin - Gallery style */
    #gallery
    {
        background-color: #444;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 520px;
    }

    #gallery ul
    { 
        list-style: none;
    }

    #gallery ul li 
    { 
        display: inline;
    }

    #gallery ul img
    {
        border: 5px solid #3e3e3e;
        border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
    }

    #gallery ul a:hover img
    {
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        border-width: 5px 5px 20px;
        color: #fff;
    }

    #gallery ul a:hover 
    { 
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
```

USAGE:
div tag with id=gallery

```
HTML:
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style-projects-jquery.css" />    

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" media="screen" />

<h2 id="example">Example</h2>
<p>Click in the image and see the <strong>jQuery lightBox plugin</strong> in action.</p>
<div id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="photos/image1.jpg" title="Utilize a flexibilidade dos seletores da jQuery e crie um grupo de imagens como desejar. $('#gallery').lightBox();">
                <img src="photos/thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If someone can help me change the .click() function...

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback:

```
$(function(){

    $('button').live('click', function() {
        $('div').load('test1.txt', function() {
            $('#gallery a').lightBox();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: How to use this callback function?

Comment: If I replace    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").load('test1.txt')});
 });
 </script> with your function...I get an error...:|

Comment: When I press the button, nothing happens

Comment: I fixed it: using document.ready function to reinitialize the lightbox in the test1.txt file :)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery live() cannot be used on custom events, document ready or any plugin calls.

You have to call the plugin again in the ajax output for this to work properly.

Comment: I just want to use ajax to load an image and aply that lightbox, I am opened to ideas...